# Camel: How to extract XML based on text value after split with namespaces?

Tags: xml, apache-camel

I'm having trouble with extracting XML from a splitting of a larger XML where namespaces are used.

The following XML is split on `<tns:tradeStatusDetails>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<tns:customerResponse xmlns:tns="http://deutsche-boerse.com/DBRegHub" xsi:schemaLocation="http://deutsche-boerse.com/DBRegHub CustomerResponse001.20_inclESMAupdates.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tns:tradeStatusReport>
    <tns:tradeStatusInformation>
      <tns:responseType>Deutsche Börse Group - Regulatory Reporting Hub - Trade Status Report</tns:responseType>
      <tns:customerId>549300GKFG0RYRRQ1414</tns:customerId>
      <tns:senderId>529900G3SW56SHYNPR95</tns:senderId>
      <tns:timestamp>2018-04-10T22:41:56.000000000</tns:timestamp>
      <tns:environment>SIM</tns:environment>
      <tns:version>001.20</tns:version>
      <tns:totalRecords>6</tns:totalRecords>
    </tns:tradeStatusInformation>

    <tns:tradeStatusDetails>
      <tns:submissionTimestamp>2018-04-10T14:22:22.096000000</tns:submissionTimestamp>
      <tns:customerTransactionId>107902</tns:customerTransactionId>
      <tns:referenceId>107902</tns:referenceId>
      <tns:reportingObligationEntityId>549300GKFG0RYRRQ1414</tns:reportingObligationEntityId>
      <tns:tradeDate>2018-04-10</tns:tradeDate>
      <tns:reportLevel>T</tns:reportLevel>
      <tns:actionType>N</tns:actionType>
      <tns:regulation>MiFIR</tns:regulation>
      <tns:recordVersion>1</tns:recordVersion>
      <tns:userField1>1</tns:userField1>
      <tns:lastUpdateTime>22:18:51.760</tns:lastUpdateTime>
      <tns:lifecycleStatus>final</tns:lifecycleStatus>
      <tns:dataUploadStatus>accepted</tns:dataUploadStatus>
      <tns:immediateValidStatus>warning</tns:immediateValidStatus>
      <tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>n/a</tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>
      <tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>n/a</tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>
      <tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>open</tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>
      <tns:postEnrichmentStatus>n/a</tns:postEnrichmentStatus>
      <tns:aggregatedValidStatus>warning</tns:aggregatedValidStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrStatus>accepted</tns:ncaTrStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrReconStatus>n/a</tns:ncaTrReconStatus>
      <tns:senderArmReconStatus>n/a</tns:senderArmReconStatus>
    </tns:tradeStatusDetails>
    <tns:tradeStatusDetails>
      <tns:submissionTimestamp>2018-04-10T14:22:22.096000000</tns:submissionTimestamp>
      <tns:customerTransactionId>107903</tns:customerTransactionId>
      <tns:referenceId>107903</tns:referenceId>
      <tns:reportingObligationEntityId>549300GKFG0RYRRQ1414</tns:reportingObligationEntityId>
      <tns:tradeDate>2018-04-10</tns:tradeDate>
      <tns:reportLevel>T</tns:reportLevel>
      <tns:actionType>N</tns:actionType>
      <tns:regulation>MiFIR</tns:regulation>
      <tns:recordVersion>1</tns:recordVersion>
      <tns:userField1>1</tns:userField1>
      <tns:lastUpdateTime>22:18:51.760</tns:lastUpdateTime>
      <tns:lifecycleStatus>final</tns:lifecycleStatus>
      <tns:dataUploadStatus>accepted</tns:dataUploadStatus>
      <tns:immediateValidStatus>warning</tns:immediateValidStatus>
      <tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>n/a</tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>
      <tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>n/a</tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>
      <tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>open</tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>
      <tns:postEnrichmentStatus>n/a</tns:postEnrichmentStatus>
      <tns:aggregatedValidStatus>warning</tns:aggregatedValidStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrStatus>accepted</tns:ncaTrStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrReconStatus>n/a</tns:ncaTrReconStatus>
      <tns:senderArmReconStatus>n/a</tns:senderArmReconStatus>
    </tns:tradeStatusDetails>
    <tns:tradeStatusDetails>
      <tns:submissionTimestamp>2018-04-10T14:22:22.096000000</tns:submissionTimestamp>
      <tns:customerTransactionId>107904</tns:customerTransactionId>
      <tns:referenceId>107904</tns:referenceId>
      <tns:reportingObligationEntityId>549300GKFG0RYRRQ1414</tns:reportingObligationEntityId>
      <tns:tradeDate>2018-04-10</tns:tradeDate>
      <tns:reportLevel>T</tns:reportLevel>
      <tns:actionType>N</tns:actionType>
      <tns:regulation>MiFIR</tns:regulation>
      <tns:recordVersion>1</tns:recordVersion>
      <tns:userField1>1</tns:userField1>
      <tns:lastUpdateTime>22:18:51.760</tns:lastUpdateTime>
      <tns:lifecycleStatus>final</tns:lifecycleStatus>
      <tns:dataUploadStatus>accepted</tns:dataUploadStatus>
      <tns:immediateValidStatus>warning</tns:immediateValidStatus>
      <tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>n/a</tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>
      <tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>n/a</tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>
      <tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>open</tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>
      <tns:postEnrichmentStatus>n/a</tns:postEnrichmentStatus>
      <tns:aggregatedValidStatus>warning</tns:aggregatedValidStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrStatus>sent</tns:ncaTrStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrReconStatus>n/a</tns:ncaTrReconStatus>
      <tns:senderArmReconStatus>n/a</tns:senderArmReconStatus>
    </tns:tradeStatusDetails>
    <tns:tradeStatusDetails>
      <tns:submissionTimestamp>2018-04-10T14:22:22.096000000</tns:submissionTimestamp>
      <tns:customerTransactionId>107905</tns:customerTransactionId>
      <tns:referenceId>107905</tns:referenceId>
      <tns:reportingObligationEntityId>549300GKFG0RYRRQ1414</tns:reportingObligationEntityId>
      <tns:tradeDate>2018-04-10</tns:tradeDate>
      <tns:reportLevel>T</tns:reportLevel>
      <tns:actionType>N</tns:actionType>
      <tns:regulation>MiFIR</tns:regulation>
      <tns:recordVersion>1</tns:recordVersion>
      <tns:userField1>1</tns:userField1>
      <tns:lastUpdateTime>22:18:51.760</tns:lastUpdateTime>
      <tns:lifecycleStatus>final</tns:lifecycleStatus>
      <tns:dataUploadStatus>accepted</tns:dataUploadStatus>
      <tns:immediateValidStatus>warning</tns:immediateValidStatus>
      <tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>n/a</tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>
      <tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>n/a</tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>
      <tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>open</tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>
      <tns:postEnrichmentStatus>n/a</tns:postEnrichmentStatus>
      <tns:aggregatedValidStatus>warning</tns:aggregatedValidStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrStatus>sent</tns:ncaTrStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrReconStatus>n/a</tns:ncaTrReconStatus>
      <tns:senderArmReconStatus>n/a</tns:senderArmReconStatus>
    </tns:tradeStatusDetails>
    <tns:tradeStatusDetails>
      <tns:submissionTimestamp>2018-04-10T14:22:22.096000000</tns:submissionTimestamp>
      <tns:customerTransactionId>107906</tns:customerTransactionId>
      <tns:referenceId>107906</tns:referenceId>
      <tns:reportingObligationEntityId>549300GKFG0RYRRQ1414</tns:reportingObligationEntityId>
      <tns:tradeDate>2018-04-10</tns:tradeDate>
      <tns:reportLevel>T</tns:reportLevel>
      <tns:actionType>N</tns:actionType>
      <tns:regulation>MiFIR</tns:regulation>
      <tns:recordVersion>1</tns:recordVersion>
      <tns:userField1>1</tns:userField1>
      <tns:lastUpdateTime>22:18:51.760</tns:lastUpdateTime>
      <tns:lifecycleStatus>final</tns:lifecycleStatus>
      <tns:dataUploadStatus>accepted</tns:dataUploadStatus>
      <tns:immediateValidStatus>warning</tns:immediateValidStatus>
      <tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>n/a</tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>
      <tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>n/a</tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>
      <tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>open</tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>
      <tns:postEnrichmentStatus>n/a</tns:postEnrichmentStatus>
      <tns:aggregatedValidStatus>warning</tns:aggregatedValidStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrStatus>sent</tns:ncaTrStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrReconStatus>n/a</tns:ncaTrReconStatus>
      <tns:senderArmReconStatus>n/a</tns:senderArmReconStatus>
    </tns:tradeStatusDetails>
    <tns:tradeStatusDetails>
      <tns:submissionTimestamp>2018-04-10T14:22:22.096000000</tns:submissionTimestamp>
      <tns:customerTransactionId>107907</tns:customerTransactionId>
      <tns:referenceId>107907</tns:referenceId>
      <tns:reportingObligationEntityId>549300GKFG0RYRRQ1414</tns:reportingObligationEntityId>
      <tns:tradeDate>2018-04-10</tns:tradeDate>
      <tns:reportLevel>T</tns:reportLevel>
      <tns:actionType>N</tns:actionType>
      <tns:regulation>MiFIR</tns:regulation>
      <tns:recordVersion>1</tns:recordVersion>
      <tns:userField1>1</tns:userField1>
      <tns:lastUpdateTime>22:18:51.760</tns:lastUpdateTime>
      <tns:lifecycleStatus>final</tns:lifecycleStatus>
      <tns:dataUploadStatus>accepted</tns:dataUploadStatus>
      <tns:immediateValidStatus>warning</tns:immediateValidStatus>
      <tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>n/a</tns:tradeReportMatchStatus>
      <tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>n/a</tns:exchangeDataMatchStatus>
      <tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>open</tns:assistedReportingMatchStatus>
      <tns:postEnrichmentStatus>n/a</tns:postEnrichmentStatus>
      <tns:aggregatedValidStatus>warning</tns:aggregatedValidStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrStatus>sent</tns:ncaTrStatus>
      <tns:ncaTrReconStatus>n/a</tns:ncaTrReconStatus>
      <tns:senderArmReconStatus>n/a</tns:senderArmReconStatus>
    </tns:tradeStatusDetails>
  </tns:tradeStatusReport>
</tns:customerResponse>
```

Within the split I must evaluate if there's a text value of ***accepted*** for tag (two cases in this example):

```
<tns:ncaTrStatus>accepted</tns:ncaTrStatus>
```

These XML will be delivered to a specific queue…

However the split cannot be parsed due to the namespace on tag (tns:)

I get the following error message:

> 2018-04-13 15:48:01:072-[Camel (LRM-Relay) thread #5 -
>   file://mifir/input/response4]
>   [Fatal Error] :1:25: The prefix "tns" for element "tns:tradeStatusDetails" is not bound.

This is my route:

```
Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("tns", "http://deutsche-boerse.com/DBRegHub");
from("{{incoming.path.xmlfile.tradestatus}}")
        .routeId("Unmarshal Trade Status (Response 4)")
        .autoStartup("{{response.tradestatus.startup}}")
        .unmarshal().zipFile()
        .split()
        .tokenizeXML("tns:tradeStatusDetails")
        .streaming()
        .log("${body}")
        .choice()
        .when()
        .xpath("//tns:ncaTrStatus/text() = 'accepted'", ns)
        .log("Transaction accepted")
        .to("{{jms.queue.reply_trades_validations}}")
        .otherwise()
        .log("${body}")
        .to("{{jms.queue.reply_trades_status}}")
        .end();
```

Using Camel version 2.21.0

SOLVED - this is the working snippet:

```
Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("tns", "http://deutsche-boerse.com/DBRegHub");

final XPathBuilder xPathBuilder = XPathBuilder.xpath("//tns:tradeStatusDetails")
                                              .namespaces(ns)
                                              .logNamespaces();

from("{{incoming.path.xmlfile.tradestatus}}")
        .routeId("Unmarshal Trade Status (Response 4)")
        .autoStartup("{{response.tradestatus.startup}}")
        .unmarshal().zipFile()
        .split(xPathBuilder)
        .parallelProcessing()
        .multicast()
        .to("direct:toCoreAccepted")
        .to("direct:toCoreAcceptedWithWarning")
        .to("{{jms.queue.reply_trades_status}}")
        .end();

from("direct:toCoreAccepted")
        .filter()
        .xpath("/tns:tradeStatusDetails[tns:ncaTrStatus = 'accepted']", ns)
        .log("Transaction accepted")
        .to("{{jms.queue.reply_trades_validations}}")
        .end();

from("direct:toCoreAcceptedWithWarnings")
        .filter()
        .xpath("/tns:tradeStatusDetails[tns:ncaTrStatus = 'accepted with warnings']", ns)
        .log("Transaction accepted with warnings")
        .to("{{jms.queue.reply_trades_validations}}")
        .end();
```

Comment: You need to configure the `tns` namespace to the XPath, see more at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/xpath-language.adoc

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the Namespace declaration in my code snippet. However this doesn't make the outcome any different.

Comment: I have read the linked document but can't really see how and where I set the namespace in that context.

Comment: SOLVED: tokenizeXML and streaming was the problem…